# Eigenenergies shift of a two-level atom in a semi-classical electric field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, quantum-optics, eigenvalue

Let's consider a two-level atom, with resonance frequency $\omega_a$, interacting with a semi-classical field, with frequency $\omega$ and Rabi-frequency $\Omega$. We could for example write our hamiltonian as:
$$
H =
\begin{pmatrix}
\omega_a & \Omega \cdot \cos(\omega t) \\
\newline \Omega \cdot \cos(\omega t) & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\, .
$$

Now the goal is to find what are the eigenenergies of this atom in an electric field. A method generally used is to use a unitary transformation and then apply the rotating wave approximation. For example I could use

$$
U =
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i(\omega_a + \omega)t/2} & 0 \\
\newline 0 & e^{i(\omega_a - \omega)t/2} \end{pmatrix}
\, .
$$

We find as transformed Hamiltonian (using $\tilde{H} = i \hbar \dot{U} U^{\dagger} + U H U^{\dagger}$)

\begin{align}
\tilde{H} &=
\frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
-(\omega_a + \omega) & 0 \\
\newline 0 & -(\omega_a - \omega) \end{pmatrix} \\
&+ 
\hbar \begin{pmatrix}
\omega_a & \frac{\Omega}{2}(e^{i \omega t} + e^{-i \omega t})e^{i \omega t} \\
\newline \frac{\Omega}{2}(e^{i \omega t} + e^{-i \omega t})e^{-i \omega t} & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\, .
\end{align}

By neglecting the fast oscillating terms (because when a derivative oscillates very fast, it has no time to influence significantly the general evolution of the function) and defining the detuning $\delta = \omega_a - \omega$ we get

$$
\tilde{H} = \frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
\delta & \Omega \\
\newline \Omega & -\delta \end{pmatrix}
\, .
$$

We can easily compute the eigenvalues of $\tilde{H}$
$$
\lambda_{\pm} = \pm \frac{\hbar}{2} \sqrt{\Omega^2+\delta^2}
\, .
$$

and in the limit where the detuning is quite big in comparison to the Rabi-frequency, $\delta \gg \Omega$, we get

$$
\lambda_{\pm} = \pm \frac{\hbar \delta}{2} \sqrt{1+\Omega^2/\delta^2} \approx \pm \frac{\hbar \delta}{2}(1+\frac{\Omega^2}{2\delta^2}) = \pm \frac{\hbar \delta}{2} \pm \frac{\hbar \Omega^2}{4 \delta}.
$$

Now comes the part where I am confused. The eigenenergies of $\tilde{H}$ are obviously not the same as the eigenvalues of $H$ (we can see it if we set for example $\Omega=0$). Is this because of the rotating wave approximation that we did or is it because of the unitary transformation? I thought (maybe wrongly) that since unitary transformations are length and angle preserving transformations, they should not affect the eigenvalues of an operator. If the change in eigenvalues comes from the unitary transformation, please tell me how I can deduce the eigenvalues of $H$ from the eigenvalues of $\tilde{H}$. More generally **explain what is the physical meaning of the eigenvalues of $\tilde{H}$ and how we can explain light shifts with this**.

Comment: *"because when a derivative oscillates very fast, it has no time to influence significantly the general evolution of the function*" Be careful with that. The rotating wave approximation is pretty good when computing eigenvalues but it can give completely wrong results for dynamics. Here's an [example](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05721) where that really mattered in real life.

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues of $H$ are time-dependent and generally not a useful thing.  I *suppose* they could be interpreted as *instantaneous* (eigen)energies, but those energies aren't useful for determining the time-dependence of the state, as you've shown: for that you need the $\lambda$'s.

> I thought (maybe wrongly) that since unitary transformations are length and angle preserving transformations, they should not affect the eigenvalues of an operator.

Your statement is true, but you're not just transforming the $\hat{H}$; rather, you're transforming the *Schrodinger equation*, and since the unitary transformation is time-dependent, the time-derivative on the LHS of the Schrodinger equation introduces a second term that is moved to the RHS and added to the transformed Hamiltonian on the RHS to make the full rotating-frame Hamiltonian.  This is why the eigenvalues are different, and this is why it is *these* eigenvalues that are important for determining the time-dependence. The instantaneous eigenvalues of the original $H$ don't take this extra term into account.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The eigenvalues of H are as you said time dependent so it is pointless to try to find these. But I am still really unsure how to interpret then the physical meaning of $\lambda_{\pm}$. I know that there is a shift in the frequencies of the emission/absorption spectral lines (AC Strak effect). But how can I find how these frequencies will be shifted? I think it would be great to add to your answer how the eigenvalues of $\tilde{H}$ should be interpreted

Answer (score 1):

As march mentioned, the energy eigenvalues are actually transformed with the unitary transformation, because we transform the Schrödinger's equation.

However, I disagree with the fact that the eigenvalues of $H$ are not really useful. I think that I actually found a way to get a good estimation of the energies eigenvalues in the non-rotating frame, and this provides a good explanation of the so called light-shift, a shift in eigenenergies due to the presence of an electric field.

But for this we also need the eigenstates of $\tilde{H}$. This can be easily found and written in the form:

$$
|+ \rangle = cos(\theta) |e \rangle + sin(\theta) |g\rangle \\
|- \rangle = sin(\theta) |e \rangle - cos(\theta) |g\rangle
$$

with
$$
tan(\theta) = \frac{1}{\Omega} \left( \sqrt{\Omega^2+\delta^2} -\delta \right)
$$

We can bring these in the non-rotating frame by taking the inverse unitary transform

$$
|+ \rangle_{non-rotating} = U^{\dagger} |+\rangle \\
|- \rangle_{non-rotating} = U^{\dagger} |-\rangle \\
$$

To find the expectation values of the energy of these in the non-rotating frame, we simply compute

$$
E_+ = \langle+|U H U^{\dagger}|+\rangle 
$$

Then using the fact that $\tilde{H} = i \hbar \dot{U} U^{\dagger} + U H U^{\dagger}$ we get

$$
E_+ = \langle+|U H U^{\dagger}|+\rangle = \langle+| \left( \tilde{H} - i \hbar \dot{U} U^{\dagger} \right) |+\rangle = \langle+|\tilde{H}|+\rangle - \langle+|i \hbar \dot{U} U^{\dagger}|+\rangle = \lambda_+ - i \hbar 
\begin{pmatrix}
cos(\theta) \\
sin(\theta) \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
i(\omega_a + \omega)/2 & 0 \\
\newline 0 & i(\omega_a - \omega)/2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
cos(\theta) \\
sin(\theta) \end{pmatrix} \\= \frac{\hbar}{2}\sqrt{\Omega^2+\delta^2} + \frac{\hbar}{2} \left( cos^2(\theta)(\omega_a +\omega) + sin^2(\theta)(\omega_a -\omega) \right)
$$

If we consider the case where $\delta \gg \Omega$, then we can use that

$$
\sqrt{\Omega^2+\delta^2} \approx \delta + \frac{\Omega^2}{2 \delta}
$$
and hence
$$
tan(\theta) \approx \frac{\Omega}{2 \delta} \ll 1 \implies sin(\theta) \approx 0, \quad cos(\theta) \approx 1
$$
We plug in these approximation into $E_+$ and get

$$
E_+ \approx \frac{\hbar}{2} \left( \delta + \frac{\Omega^2}{2 \delta} + \omega_a + \omega \right) = \frac{\hbar}{2} \left( \omega_a - \omega + \frac{\Omega^2}{2 \delta} + \omega_a + \omega \right) = \hbar \omega_a + \hbar\frac{\Omega^2}{4 \delta}
$$

Similarly for $E_-$ we get

$$
E_- = -\frac{\hbar}{2}\sqrt{\Omega^2+\delta^2} + \frac{\hbar}{2} \left( sin^2(\theta)(\omega_a +\omega) + cos^2(\theta)(\omega_a -\omega) \right)
\approx \frac{\hbar}{2} \left( -\delta - \frac{\Omega^2}{2 \delta} + \omega_a - \omega \right) = -\hbar\frac{\Omega^2}{4 \delta}
$$

So with this we that indeed there is only a slight shift of the energies in the non-rotating frame. We see that for a red detuned light, $\omega < \omega_a \implies \delta > 0$, so the eigenenergies are brought further apart which explains why atoms in the ground state get attracted by such a laser frequency (the electron wants to go in a lower energy state). on the other hand, if it is blue detuned, $\omega > \omega_a \implies \delta < 0$, the the eigenenrgies are brought closer to each other. This is therefor repulsive for the atom.

Comment: I mean, you're right about them being useful in some cases; that's what I meant by saying that they are *generally* not useful.  Consider the adiabatic approximation, in which a Hamiltonian can change slowly enough that the populations of the *instantaneous* eigenstates remain constant, and hence the instantaneous eigenenergies are generally meaningful quantities. I think in your post, some form of the the adiabatic approximation is being used, "parameterized" by the inequality $\delta \ll \Omega$. So sure, they *can* be meaninful quantities, but only in special cases.